# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. Sitecore web api item access in console application

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I am trying to access Sitecore items using Webapi in console application its throwing an error - `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`.

code:-

```
var url = "https://sc103sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/item/110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9";
         
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", "admin");
           request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Password", "b");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            var response = request.GetResponse();
```

patch added :

```
<site name="website">
      <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
      <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadWrite</patch:attribute>
      <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">true</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need first to authenticate with Sitecore and perform your different requests by including the authentication session.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html
[image: 403- Forbidden. The request is not permitted for security reasons.]

Code:

```
ublic static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var authUrl = "https://<domain>/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login";
        var authData = new Authentication
        {
            Domain = "sitecore",
            Username = "admin",
            Password = "b"
        };

        var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authUrl);

        authRequest.Method = "POST";
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        var requestAuthBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authData);

        var authDatas = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestAuthBody);

        using (var dataStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(authDatas, 0, authDatas.Length);
        }

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        authRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        var authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine($"Login Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)authResponse).StatusDescription}");

        authResponse.Close();

        var emailObj = new ItemRequest
        {
            ItemName = "Test APi 4",
            TemplateID = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}",
            Title = "Test API TITLE",
            Text = "TEST API TEXT"
        };

        var url = "https://<domain>/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailObj);

        var data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestBody);

        using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine($"Item Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred. Message: {ex.Message}.\r\n StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}.\r\n InnerException: {ex.InnerException}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Refer below link that uses Sitecore itemService Rest api and Console.
https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/sitecore-itemservice-rest-api/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I followed the same article but there but it does not work for me. Same issue with this as well.

Comment: What is the result in authResponse? Is it returns successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` for the value of `Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy`:

```
<!--   SITECORE SERVICES SECURITY POLICY
  Specifies the Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.IAuthorizePolicy derived type that will set the security policy 
  for the Sitecore services.
  
  Policies:
  
  Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOffPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
  - Policy denies access to all Entity and Item Services
  
  Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
  - Policy denies access to all Entity and Item Services from requests originating from remote clients
  
  Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
  - Policy allows access to all Entity and Item Services
  
  Default: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure      
-->

<setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" />
```

If you want to allow access from application located on another server, you will need `ServicesOnPolicy` to be configured.

Be aware that this can potentially create security issues.

Read more in Sitecore documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-services-client-security.html

Additionally, remember to include `sitecore` domain name in `X-Scitemwebapi-Username`

```
request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", @"sitecore\admin");
```

Comment: I tried that already. <setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy , Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" patch:source="Sitecore.Services.Client.config"/>

Comment: try to include sitecore domain name in X-Scitemwebapi-Username `request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", @"sitecore\admin");`